# What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, msys2, msys

MSYS2 is said to have different [*environments*](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/).

What are they? How do I choose which one to use? What's the difference between MINGW64 and UCRT64?

---

<sub>(This Q&A is intended as a canonical duplicate on this topic.)</sub>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [the official manual](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/). Following environments are available: UCRT64, MINGW64, CLANG64, MSYS, and others (see link).

UCRT64 is a good default, MINGW64 is popular too, but the alternatives are explained below.

The different environments exist to produce different kinds of Windows executables, or do that with different tools.

Each environment **has its own packages** (compilers, precompiled libraries, and various executables), which can be distinguished by the common prefix in the package names (e.g. `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-...` for UCRT64).

Each environment **installs its files to a separate subdirectory** inside the MSYS2 installation, e.g. UCRT64 installs to `C:\msys64\ucrt64`, and so on (except MSYS notably installs to `C:\msys64\usr`, and some packages directly to `C:\msys64`).

Each environment **has the respective shortcut in the Start menu**, which starts the MSYS2 terminal and adds the respective directory to its `PATH`. E.g. the `MSYS2 UCRT64` starts with `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` in the PATH.

- By default MSYS2 ignores the system-wide `PATH` setting, and starts its terminal with a fully customized `PATH`, run `echo $PATH` to see it.
- All environments also add `C:\msys64\usr\bin` to `PATH` after `C:\msys64\<env>\bin`. So, in a way, all environments inherit from the MSYS environment. More on that below.
- The environments also customize some other environment variables, run `printenv` to see for yourself.

MSYS2 terminal **displays the current environment in magenta text** in the terminal prompt.

#### How do I use a specific environment?

1. All **packages you install must have their name prefixed** appropriately. E.g. for UCRT64, `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-...` (see the table below for other environments).

   This applies to all compilers, libraries, etc. So if you want to install GCC in UCRT64, use `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc`, NOT `pacman -S gcc`.

   The only exception are utilites ported from Linux which are unrelated to the compilation process, such as `grep`, `sed`, `bash`, etc, which don't have prefixed packages.

   Unprefixed packages all belong to the MSYS environment.

   **WARNING:** Normally you can install packages for multiple environments, and they won't interfere with each other, **except** the unprefixed MSYS packages are in the `PATH` for **all** the environments, and some of them **will** get in your way. E.g if you install `pacman -S gcc`, forget to install `pacman -S ...-gcc`, then try to run `gcc` from any environment other than MSYS, you'll call GCC of the MSYS environment, instead of your environment's GCC. Most of the time this is not what you want, and you'll get cryptic errors.

   <sup>(The notable exception is `make`, its prefixed and unprefixed packages use different executable names, so they don't conflict, can be installed at the same time, and both are viable options. The prefixed version (which installs as `mingw32-make`) works much faster, but the unprefixed one offers better Linux compatibility by having its path functions return Linux-style paths.)</sup>
2. If you use MSYS2 terminal, **start the terminal using the appropriate shortcut**.

   The shortcuts have the environment names in them, e.g. for UCRT64 use the `MSYS2 UCRT64` shortcut.
3. If you don't use the MSYS2 terminal and call the tools from elsewhere, add the appropriate directory to PATH, e.g. for UCRT64 add `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin`.

   In rare cases you may also need to add `C:\msys64\usr\bin`. If you do, make sure to add it *after* the previously mentioned directory.

   To avoid problems, it's a good idea to have those directories directly at the beginning of the `PATH` (both system-wide and user-specific).

#### How do I choose the environment?

UCRT64 should be a good default for most purposes.

Otherwise the choice depends on:

- Preferred compiled: GCC or Clang (some provide both).
- Preferred C++ standard library (GCC's libstdc++ or Clang's libc++, some provide both).
- Preferred C standard library (the old MSVCRT, or the new UCRT with the UTF-8 support).
- Whether you need the sanitizers (Address Sanitizer, UB sanitizer, etc).
- Whether you need [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)-style POSIX emulation.
- Whether you want to produce [executables for ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/overview).

| Environment | UCRT64 | MINGW64 | CLANG64 | MSYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Installs to** <sup>(relative to MSYS2 installation directory, normally `C:\msys64\...`)</sup> | `/ucrt64` | `/mingw64` | `/clang64` | `/usr` <sup>(some packages to `/`?)</sup> |
| **Package prefix** | `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-` | `mingw-w64-x86_64-` | `mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-` | none |
| **Target architecture** | x86_64 | x86_64 | x86_64 | Cygwin x86_64 |
| **Compiler** | GCC (also Clang) | GCC (also Clang) | Clang | GCC (also Clang) <sup>(might be outdated)</sup> |
| **C++ standard library** | libstdc++ (also libc++) | libstdc++ (also libc++) | libc++ | libstdc++ |
| **C standard library** | UCRT | MSVCRT | UCRT | Cygwin |
| **Sanitizers** | No<sup>1</sup> | No<sup>1</sup> | YES | No<sup>1</sup> |

<sup>1 — [UBSan can be made to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59083808/2752075), but it can't print diagnostics and can only crash on error.</sup>

**Target architecture variants:**

- **32-bit**

  All environments above produce x64 executables (aka x86_64).

  There are also environments for x32 executables (aka i686): `MINGW32` and `CLANG32`.

  They are similar to the respective x64 environments, except the files are installed to the `/...32` directories instead of `/...64`, and the package prefixes contain `i686` in place of `x86_64`.
- **ARM**

  All environments above produce executables for [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86), either x32 or x64. This is what the majority of desktops and laptops run on.

  Apparently there are now some [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family) laptops running Windows too. And while they can [emulate x86 to run x86 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/overview), native ARM applications should have better performance.

  The CLANGARM64 environment can be used to produce ARM (aka aarch64) apps. It's similar to CLANG64, except the files are installed to `/clangarm64`, and the packages are prefixed with `mingw-w64-clang-aarch64-`.

**C standard libraries, MSVCRT vs UCRT:**

[The manual](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/#msvcrt-vs-ucrt) explains the difference well.

In short:

- MSVCRT (`msvcrt.dll`):

  - Old, comes from Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0.
  - This was the only option for MinGW until a few years ago.
  - No UTF-8 support for paths, must use UTF-16 and `wchar_t` to handle unicode in paths.
- UCRT (`ucrtbase.dll`)

  - New and shiny, this is what the contemporary Visual Studio uses.
  - Available by default on Windows 10, on prior Windows versions must be installed manually.
  - Supports UTF-8 in paths, if you enable a UTF-8 locale in your application.

**The MSYS environment:**

This environment is based on MSYS2's own fork of [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), which is a POSIX emulation layer.

It's primarily used to compile Linux applications that were not written in a cross-platform manner. Arguably, *new* applications should always be written in a cross-platform manner in the first place, and then compiled using the other environments.

MSYS2 uses it to provide `bash`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, and other command line utilities commonly used on Linux.

From my limited understanding, MSYS applications are normally used exclusively inside of the MSYS2 shell for development purposes, and not distrbuted to users.

Among other things, applications compiled with it see all paths in Linux style: with forward slashes `/` as separators, with the `/` (root) directory mapped to the MSYS2 installation directory, and `/c` magically mapped to `C:\` (similary for other drive letters). They also get access to emulated Linux-specific functions, such as `fork()`.

This emulation layer has a performance cost.

It should also be noted that MSYS seems to not provide as much libraries (and packages in general) as the other environments, and doesn't receive compiler updates as frequently.

Comment: I thought Clang could produce the code for any target architecture: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

Comment: @AlexandrZarubkin It can. Clangs from different envs just have different default targets. They are also compiled with different compilers (default compilers for each env), but this shouldn't have a practical difference.