# MSYS2 - 'pip3 install PyQt5' fails with error "Could not build wheels for sip"?

Tags: pip, pyqt5, msys

I have installed the MSYS2 package mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5. The rest of my packages are all up-to-date.

However, I have apparently not installed the PyQt5 *module*, so something that relies on it fails. (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5')

I have tried to fix this by installing the module using Pip. However, this fails:

```
pip3 install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [178 lines of output]
      Collecting sip<7,>=6.6.2
        Using cached sip-6.7.10.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting PyQt-builder<2,>=1.14.1
        Obtaining dependency information for PyQt-builder<2,>=1.14.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/74/f8bd2e249e080f0a55e890171a0d264781bfed8ae6da7286174fa4da7b3e/PyQt_builder-1.15.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached PyQt_builder-1.15.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
      Collecting packaging (from sip<7,>=6.6.2)
        Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
      Collecting ply (from sip<7,>=6.6.2)
        Using cached ply-3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
      Collecting setuptools (from sip<7,>=6.6.2)
        Obtaining dependency information for setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/42/be1c7bbdd83e1bfb160c94b9cafd8e25efc7400346cf7ccdbdb452c467fa/setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
      Using cached PyQt_builder-1.15.2-py3-none-any.whl (3.7 MB)
      Using cached setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (804 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: sip
        Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [144 lines of output]
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running build_py
            creating build
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/abstract_builder.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/abstract_project.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/api.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/argument_parser.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/bindings.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/bindings_configuration.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/buildable.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/builder.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/configurable.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/distutils_builder.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/exceptions.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/installable.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/project.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/pyproject.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/py_versions.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/setuptools_builder.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/toml.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/version.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            copying sipbuild/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/distinfo
            copying sipbuild/distinfo/distinfo.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/distinfo
            copying sipbuild/distinfo/main.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/distinfo
            copying sipbuild/distinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/distinfo
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/error_log.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/instantiations.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/python_slots.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/scoped_name.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/specification.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/templates.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/utils.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            copying sipbuild/generator/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module
            copying sipbuild/module/abi_version.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module
            copying sipbuild/module/main.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module
            copying sipbuild/module/module.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module
            copying sipbuild/module/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/tools
            copying sipbuild/tools/build.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/tools
            copying sipbuild/tools/install.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/tools
            copying sipbuild/tools/sdist.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/tools
            copying sipbuild/tools/wheel.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/tools
            copying sipbuild/tools/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/tools
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/api.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/extracts.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/pyi.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/type_hints.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/xml.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/annotations.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/parser.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/parser_manager.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/parsetab.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/python_exceptions.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/rules.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/tokens.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            copying sipbuild/generator/parser/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/parser
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/resolver
            copying sipbuild/generator/resolver/resolver.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/resolver
            copying sipbuild/generator/resolver/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/resolver
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/argument.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/base_formatter.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/enum.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/klass.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/overload.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/scoped.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/signature.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/template.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/utils.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/value_list.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/variable.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            copying sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/generator/outputs/formatters
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/apiversions.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/bool.cpp -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/descriptors.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/int_convertors.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/LICENSE -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/LICENSE-GPL2 -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/LICENSE-GPL3 -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/MANIFEST.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/objmap.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/pyproject.toml -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/qtlib.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/README.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/setup.cfg.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/setup.py.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/sip.h.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/sip.pyi -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/sip.rst.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/sipint.h -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/siplib.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/sip_array.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/sip_array.h -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/threads.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            copying sipbuild/module/source/12/voidptr.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/12
            creating build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/LICENSE -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/LICENSE-GPL2 -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/LICENSE-GPL3 -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/MANIFEST.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/pyproject.toml -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/README.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/setup.cfg.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/setup.py.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip.h.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip.pyi -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip.rst.in -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_array.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_array.h -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_bool.cpp -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_core.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_core.h -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_descriptors.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_enum.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_enum.h -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_int_convertors.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_object_map.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_threads.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            copying sipbuild/module/source/13/sip_voidptr.c -> build/lib.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/sipbuild/module/source/13
            running build_ext
            building 'sipbuild.code_generator' extension
            creating build/temp.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311
            creating build/temp.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/code_generator
            gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Icode_generator -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c code_generator/gencode.c -o build/temp.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/code_generator/gencode.o
            gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Icode_generator -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c code_generator/heap.c -o build/temp.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/code_generator/heap.o
            gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Icode_generator -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c code_generator/py2c.c -o build/temp.mingw64_nt-10.0-19045-3.4.7.x86_64-x86_64-cpython-311/code_generator/py2c.o
            In file included from D:/msys64/usr/include/python3.11/Python.h:38,
                             from code_generator/py2c.c:25:
            D:/msys64/usr/include/python3.11/pyport.h:236:10: fatal error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory
              236 | #include <sys/select.h>
                  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            compilation terminated.
            error: command '/mingw64/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
      Failed to build sip
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this error is?

Comment: What does `which pip3` say? The fact that `/usr/include` is mentioned is weird, since it doesn't belong to the MINGW64 environment, unlike `mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5`. [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075)

Comment: Windows doesn't have `sys/select.h`.  The build it confused about your host.  You might check here for assistance:  https://github.com/bji/libs3/blob/master/inc/mingw/sys/select.h

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I get back '/usr/bin/pip'

Comment: This looks wrong, shouldn't it be `/mingw64/bin/pip`? This means you installed `python-pip` instead of `mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pip`.

Comment: Thanks! That's fixed the pip issue. However, now it states PyQt5 is already installed. So why I'm getting the missing module error, I have no idea. You can put this as an answer and I'll mark it as complete.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd rather vote to close as a duplicate of the linked Q&A.

Comment: I'm familiar with the linked Q+A. Just made a mistake somewhere in installing that package. Everything else is properly installed as mingw-w64-x86_64-packagename as intended.