# compilation with msys2/ming64, sighandler_t type unkown

Tags: c++, mingw, msys2

I'm supposed to compile an application originally developed for linux in windows. People before me used to do that thorugh msys2 and mingw.

When building, I encounter an error concerning the sighandler_t type.

Looking at the linux version, this type is defined is /usr/include/signal.h.
In msys2, inside C:\msys64\ming64\include I can find a signal.h, but it has very little in common with the linux version and in particular does not define sighandler_t.

Is there a specific package I need in msys2 for this to work ? Should i replace sighandler_t and if so, with what ?

Comment: MSYS2 has different compiler flavors ([What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075)). Perhaps try the MSYS one instead of MINGW64?

Comment: `cross-compiling` isn't the right tag if you compile on Windows for Windows.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The same application used to be compiled with mingw so it might not be the best, and I will look into the other options, but I know that it is at least possible