# How do I know which DLLs I need to include to properly build a project on windows using cmake and mingw?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl-2, msys2

I have a small C++17 program I wrote using a few SDL2 libraries. I created the project using Cmake, ninja, MSYS2, and MinGW. The exe I generate executes as expected when launching through a MSYS/mingw terminal. However launching the program outside of that terminal results in missing DLL errors (libwinpthread-1.dll, for example). Just as I need to include SDL2's DLLs, do I also need to include some MinGW DLLs if I want to distribute this to a system that doesn't have MinGW installed or added to the Path?

I am using a MSYS2/MinGW terminal to "mimic" a Linux terminal with a package manager. I run CMake to find the required packages and create a build script. Then I use Ninja to build the project, which at some point invokes MinGW's g++ port to compile the necessary files. Is this correct?

Comment: [https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) or [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, install `ntldd` using `pacman -S ...-ntldd` (e.g. `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ntldd` for the [MINGW64 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075)).

Run `ntldd -R my_program.exe` (which is equivalent to `ldd my_program` on Linux).

It will output a list of DLLs. Out of those DLLs:

- Copy all DLLs in the list that are in your compiler's `bin` directory.
- Copy DLLs of any libraries that you intentionally, manually linked.
- Ignore the rest, such as DLLs in `C:\Windows` and in directories in PATH.

It's also a good idea to check every DLL ignored in the third category, make sure that it doesn't also exist under a different path (one of the two first categories). If there is overlap, you need to re-run `ntldd` with offending directories removed from PATH (or, if there's stuff in `C:\Windows`, you need to either clear it up, or copy your DLLs right next to the .exe for them to have priority).

This is usually not a problem if you run within MSYS2 shell, since it clears the PATH, unless you somehow installed custom DLLs to `C:\Windows\**`.

---

Doing the same thing under Wine is quirky. It ships (sometimes?) its own `OpenAL32.dll` in its `C:\Windows`, which has priority over anything in PATH.

So to get this procedure working reliably, I had to copy all my dependency DLLs next to the executable before running `ntldd`. Since I build OpenAL myself instead of installing from MSYS2, I opted to copy all self-built dependencies next to the .exe. If you instead install stuff from MSYS2, you'll probably need to temporarily copy every .dll in its `bin` directory instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, I copy the above mentioned DLLs into my project folder, right? Will the exe automatically search in the current directory and subdirectories for required DLLs? Do I need to inform CMake of the DLLS? I appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: @Dan I don't know how to convince CMake to do it, I myself do it with makefiles. `.exe` searches only the directory it's placed in for the DLLs, not the current directory and not subdirectories of either. (Then as a fallback, it searches `C:\Windows` (and some subdirs of that) and PATH.) So you distribute .exe and .dlls in the same directory. And keep them in the same directory during development too, unless you always operate with a carefully set up PATH.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `ntldd` works for most binaries. Interestingly, it gives `Segmentation fault` for a 32-bit console program I created with C++Builder 6, while [`ListDLLs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls) gives the expected output (my program waits for input).  Do you have any idea (hint) what could be the cause?

Comment: @Wolf Maybe it only handles apps with the same arch as itself? MSYS2 should have x32 ntldd too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Admittedly, I could have been clearer: `ntldd` also worked with other 32-bit binaries. So I assumed that the environment (PATH) might be causing the problems. After checking `ntldd.exe ntldd.exe` to make sure it was standalone, I copied it to my `tools` directory, which is in my Windows PATH. As you would expect, I now get equivalent results in the Windows console to those described above. The only difference is that the output is blank on error instead of showing `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: @Wolf No output often means that the app can't find some DLLs it needs. You shouldn't move ntldd from its installation directory (where the required DLLs are installed). Ntldd itself (if not moved this way) will not break because of PATH contents, same as any app that has all DLLs it uses in the same directory. It's possible that having MSYS2 in PATH breaks some other app (maybe include yours) that doesn't have DLLs in right places, in that case you can remove MSYS2 from PATH and start ntldd with the absolute path.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for taking the time. I do realize that we shouldn't normally move binaries out of their instrumentation folder, BTW: I *copied* in this case, because the only direct dependencies `ntldd` has, are `imagehlp.dll => C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\imagehlp.dll`, `KERNEL32.dll => C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll` and `msvcrt.dll => C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll`. `MSYS` in not in my Windows `PATH`.

Comment: @Wolf Yeah, true, didn't realize it doesn't need any MSYS2 DLLs. Should work then, not sure what's going on.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for your help so far. If I find the time to make a separate SO question out of it, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

first stop is always the [dependency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to know what dlls you need at runtime, any dll that is not in `C:\Windows` needs to be shipped with your executable in the same folder.

you could use the `-static` option of mingw to static link those dependencies and produce a binary that doesn't need any dlls from mingw, you only need to link your extra dlls, but the produced dlls/executables will have notably larger size.

if you don't statically link mingw libraries then the most basic dependencies are `libgcc` and `libstdc++` for c++, but if you use threads you will need `libwinpthread` and if you use openmp you need `libgomp` and the list goes on, so it's best to use a dependency walker when you are not sure.