# libcrypto-x64.dll was missing

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, exe, libcrypto

I make an executable file using cmake, and it runs perfectly on my computer, but when I share it to another computer and I open it, it says libcrypto-x64.dll was missing. I tried to find it on web and searched everything but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Well if it runs on your computer you most likely have `libcrypto-x64.dll` somewhere on your computer perhaps in one of the folders of your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Also it's rarely a good idea to do a web search to download a dll. One reason is there can be many different versions of the dll especially with c++ where the compilers can be incompatible.

Comment: i did search my files to find that libcrypto-x64.dll but still cant find anything

Comment: Are you sure it was not named `libcrypto-3-x64.dll` I have that file in `c:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

Comment: yes i am sure i have screenshot https://imgur.com/a/bon52qT

Comment: If you are using MinGW for your compiler maybe this program will help you find where this file exists on your PC: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196666/how-do-i-know-which-dlls-i-need-to-include-to-properly-build-a-project-on-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196666/how-do-i-know-which-dlls-i-need-to-include-to-properly-build-a-project-on-window)

Comment: If you are using msvc here is a good tool for the same search: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: thanks for the help i already fixed it i rebuild all the files then it worked