# C++. Ability to run executable file with external libraries on another pc

Tags: c++, linker, external, lib

If I created a project using extenral library, `raylib`, for instance. I installed this library so `raylib.h` file is in ..\msys64\mingw64\include\ and I can run my program. But is there any ways to compile my main file and link it the way I'll be able to run it on other pc, where `raylib` library is not installed? Or anyway I'll have to install all the libraries I used on the other pc where I want to run executable file? I know it sounds weird, but I can't fully understand what the linker does when I write `-lraylib` parameter: `g++ main.cpp -lraylib -o main`
Does `libraylib` file have a pre-compiled implemintaion code, doesn't it? And if it does, the linker just "combine" my main file and `raylib` library file, right?

I've complied and linked some project that uses `raylib` but I couldn't run it on another pc, the error said I had no necessary libraries installed to run .exe

Comment: To install it on another PC you need to deploy all of the dependent dlls with your application. At work I have used an NSIS based installer since I started using CMake in 2008 before that I used Innosetup and installshield.

Comment: This answer from @HolyBlackCat should help you find the dependent dlls: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77196785/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77196785/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm thank you, but if I have a static library .a as I know it has archieved compiled implemintaion code, so doesn't it mean that all the library code I need will aslo be linked in executable file. So another pc will be able to run it

Comment: You may need runtime for your compiler depending on how you built your executable. The link in my second comment will tell you all the needed dependencies.

Comment: `g++ main.cpp -lraylib -o main` you didn't tell it to use static runtime.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you again. going to read that topic

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/26107550/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26107550/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm does "statically" mean that the library code will be linked to executable file? Not in runtime, right?

Comment: `g++ main.cpp -lraylib -o main` says to use the dll / shared object runtime since that is the default.