# Clangd cant find standar library headers and gives weird errors for everything

Tags: c++, vscode-extensions, clangd, vscodium

Clangd vscode's extension keeps giving me weird squigglys for #includes and standard types.

**My setup:** Win11. Fresh intall. I've installed both GCC/G++ and CLANG with MYSYS (following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) guide), I've edited PATH to include the relevant directories, I have VSCode's fork VSCodium, and I've installed Clangd LS and Clangd extension for VSCodium.

**My problem**: Clangd keeps giving me weird incorrect squiggly errors for the most common things, such as trying to pass a `std::string` or a c-string (const * char[], const char[]) to `std::cout`. e.g.

```cpp
class someClass
{
...
public:
    void someMethod()
    {
        if (this->someFuncThatReturnsBool())
        {   
            std::cout << "A simple \\n-terminated string literal \n";
                  //^^^^^^
                  // "Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const char *')" 
        }
        return;
    };
};
```

It also keeps giving me some include errors regarding both include paths for headers that are *definetly were they're suposed to be*. e.g. [error trying to `#include <iostream>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NXK5.png), in some cases it states that i should replace <> with "", in others it just says it cant find the relevant header files.

**I know this are false errors, as my program compiles both with g++ and clang**

**(unsuccesful) Attempts to fix this**:

- I've uninstalled and re-installed all relevant programs.
- I've set configurations for clangd (both at global and project scope), adding "compiler flags" indicating the include directory path, the standard to use, &c. in a `.clangd` config file
- I've tryed using the [`--query-driver` flag as shown in Clangd's FAQ](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc)

I've searched on google, looked into the FAQ, search for other qa in this site, and can't find anything. Thank you in advanced

**EDIT: [ANSWER FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77207539/22049099)**
[@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) suggested that the problem could be in Clangd LS being installed by the VSC extension. Indeed, I deleted the binary, installed Clangd LS (as part of the `clang-extra-tools` package) with MYSYS

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-clang-extra-tools
```

and then specified the path to `clangd.exe` inside the VSC extension configuration GUI and now everything works as intended.

Comment: `--query-driver` is what I would recommend. To help diagnose why it's not working, could you attach [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) taken with `--log=verbose` when using `--query-driver`?

Comment: Where did you install Clangd (the language server) from, MSYS2 or official Clang builds? Or the VSC extension installed it for you? If you're using MSYS2 GCC, you should install Clangd from MSYS2, then things will work out of the box. Specify path to it in VSC settings.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, indeed Clgand LS was installed for me by the VSC extention. I've uninstalled both it and Clangd's VSC extension. Then installed the LS via MYSYS2 as you suggested and now everything works fine. Please make this an answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @HighCommander4 thanks to you too. It's allready solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler comes from MSYS2, the easiest option is to install Clangd (`clangd.exe`, the language server) from MSYS2 as well, as opposed to using the official Clang installer or letting VSC extension download it.

Then specify the path to it in VSC settings: `"clangd.path": "path/to/clangd",`.

MSYS2's Clangd uses the same default flags as the MSYS2's compilers.

If MSYS2's Clangd misbehaves (earlier versions used to do so), you can use the official build as long as you specify the correct compiler flags for it, in `"clangd.fallbackFlags"` or elsewhere (which would probably include at least `--target=?? --sysroot=??`, where the former is the target triplet, and the latter is probably `path/to/mingw64` (replace `mingw64` according to your [MSYS2 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075))).