# Different GCC compilers in in MSYS2

Tags: gcc, mingw, msys2

- What is also the difference between the gcc compiler https://packages.msys2.org/package/gcc?repo=msys&variant=x86_64 and mingw-gcc compiler https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc  in MSYS2? Both gcc compilers generate .exe executables.
- Dooes MSYS2 use the MinGW GCC distribution or they use their own abstraction layers to use Linux commands such as gcc?

Thx!

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: (2) is explained in [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075)

Comment: Ok, this is 3 questions instead of 4, you need to remove 2 more. :P Something tells me that (1) and (2) are unrelated.

Comment: So I checked your reponse in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552264/what-are-msys2-environments-how-do-i-pick-one and this answers my questions regarding MSYS. Thx!

Comment: I used this to check MinGW issue but it seems like in both cases (gcc and mingw32-gcc) we have msvcrt.dll as RT environment..

Comment: Yep, that's why I said that those questions are probably unrelated. `mingw32-gcc` and `gcc` are probably the same compiler.