# How to statically link binary with curl library on MSYS2?

Tags: c, libcurl, static-linking, msys2

I'm using UCRT64 profile in MSYS2.
Here is source code for example that I'm trying to compile.

```
/***************************************************************************
 *                                  _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
 *
 * Copyright (C) Daniel Stenberg, <daniel@haxx.se>, et al.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution. The terms
 * are also available at https://curl.se/docs/copyright.html.
 *
 * You may opt to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, under the terms of the COPYING file.
 *
 * This software is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: curl
 *
 ***************************************************************************/
/* <DESC>
 * Use CURLOPT_RESOLVE to feed custom IP addresses for given host name + port
 * number combinations.
 * </DESC>
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

     /* Each single name resolve string should be written using the format
     HOST:PORT:ADDRESS where HOST is the name libcurl will try to resolve,
     PORT is the port number of the service where libcurl wants to connect to
     the HOST and ADDRESS is the numerical IP address
   */
    struct curl_slist *host = curl_slist_append(NULL,
                                              "example.com:443:127.0.0.1");

     curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, host);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

         /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      }

     curl_slist_free_all(host);

     return (int)res;
  }
```

Here is a command to build.

```
gcc -static-libgcc --static `pkg-config.exe --cflags --static libcurl` `pkg-config.exe --libs --static libcurl` main.c
```

Output of pkg-config commands:

```
$ pkg-config.exe --libs --static libcurl                                                            -lcurl -lnghttp2 -lssh2 -lssh2 -lpsl -lbcrypt -ladvapi32 -lcrypt32 -lbcrypt -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lzstd -lzstd -lbrotlidec -lbrotlidec -lz -lws2_32 -lbrotlidec -lbrotlicommon -lidn2 -liconv -lunistring
```

```
$ pkg-config.exe --cflags --static libcurl
-DCURL_STATICLIB
```

Here is linking errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGUqsew.o:main.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGUqsew.o:main.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGUqsew.o:main.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGUqsew.o:main.c:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGUqsew.o:main.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGUqsew.o:main.c:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGUqsew.o:main.c:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `curl_slist_free_all'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong and how to achieve statically linked executable?

I've tried using same command with other profiles. Also I've tried to compile this with MSYS2 profile, libcurl-devel package and `curl-config --cflags` `curl-config --static-libs` flags. It didn't helped either.

Comment: Did you install `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl`, `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-gnutls` or `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-winssl`?

Comment: *"I'm using UCRT64 profile"* You're not using the correct compiler for that profile. You're using `/usr/bin/gcc`, while you should be using `/ucrt64/bin/gcc`. The former directory must not be in your PATH, or at least it should be after the latter in the PATH. If you're building from MSYS2 terminal, you didn't launch it correctly (use the shortcut with UCRT64 in the name), because it's supposed to configure the path automatically.

Comment: You might also want to `pacman -R gcc` to remove `/usr/bin/gcc`, there's little reason to have it installed. Does this answer your question? [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552265/2752075)

Comment: @HollyBlackCat Yes, it looks like OP hasn't installed the `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc` package.

Comment: In your build command, the linker options need to appear after the file parameters (`main.c`) like this: `gcc -static-libgcc --static \`pkg-config.exe --cflags --static libcurl\` main.c \`pkg-config.exe --libs --static libcurl\``

Answer (score 1):

In the MSYS2 UCRT 64-bit profile, make sure that suitable `gcc` and `curl` packages are installed for the environment:

```sh
pacman -S --needed mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl
```

In the build command, make sure the linker options appear after the input files (`main.c`) like this:

```sh
gcc -static-libgcc --static `pkg-config.exe --cflags --static libcurl` main.c `pkg-config.exe --libs --static libcurl`
```

The executable will be called `a.exe`.  Use the `-o` option to change the name when compiling:

```sh
gcc -static-libgcc --static `pkg-config.exe --cflags --static libcurl` main.c -o myprog `pkg-config.exe --libs --static libcurl`
```

With the above command, the executable will be called `myprog.exe`.