# Linking Error in MSYS Environment: Cannot find -ldl in ElmerFEM Project

Tags: cmake, fortran, linker-errors, mingw-w64, msys2

I am working on compiling the ElmerFEM project in an MSYS environment on Windows, and I am encountering a linker error during the build process. Specifically, the error occurs when linking a Fortran shared library (msys-elmersolver.dll). The error message is as follows:

```
[ 56%] Linking Fortran shared library msys-elmersolver.dll
cd "/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/fem/src" && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/c/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe  -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-import -o msys-elmersolver.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libelmersolver.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/AddrFunc.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/NavierStokes.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/NavierStokesGeneral.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/NavierStokesCylindrical.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Lists.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/DiffuseConvectiveAnisotropic.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/LoadMod.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/DiffuseConvectiveGeneralAnisotropic.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/PElementMaps.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/PElementBase.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ElementDescription.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Integration.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ListMatrixArray.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ModelDescription.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/GeneralUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Stress.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/StressGeneral.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/LinearAlgebra.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/CoordinateSystems.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ListMatrix.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/CRSMatrix.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/BandMatrix.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/BandwidthOptimize.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/BlockSolve.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MaterialModels.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/DirectSolve.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/IterSolve.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/IterativeMethods.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/TimeIntegrate.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Types.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolveBand.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ElementUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Radiation.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/fft.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Load.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Differentials.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/FreeSurface.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Walls.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolverUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolveSBand.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/CPUTime.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Interpolation.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MainUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Adaptive.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/EigenSolve.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/HashTable.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MeshUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SaveUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SParIterGlobals.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SParIterComm.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SParIterPrecond.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SParIterSolver.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Messages.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Multigrid.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Smoothers.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ClusteringMethods.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ParallelUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ParallelEigenSolve.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/solve_cmplx.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/solve_real.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MGPrec.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/DefUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MeshPartition.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MeshRemeshing.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/RadiationFactors.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/f_stubs.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ExchangeCorrelations.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolveHypre.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/amgx.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolverActivate_x.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolveTrilinos.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolveSuperLU.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/umf4_f77wrapper.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/VankaCreate.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ParticleUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Feti.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/cholmod.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/InterpolateMeshToMesh.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/InterpVarToVar.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/LinearForms.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/H1Basis.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/CircuitUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/BackwardError.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ElmerSolver.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MagnetoDynamicsUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ComponentUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/ZirkaHysteresis.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/SolidMechanicsUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MatrixAssembly.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/OptimizationUtils.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/MeshGenerate.o CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Lua.o   -L"/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/fem/src"  -L"/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/matc/src"  -L"/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/umfpack/src/umfpack"  -L"/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/umfpack/src/amd"  -L"/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/fhutiter/src"  -L"/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/fem/src/binio"  -L"/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/mathlibs/src/arpack"  libmpi_stubs.dll.a ../../matc/src/libmatc.dll.a ../../umfpack/src/umfpack/libumfpack.a ../../umfpack/src/amd/libamd.a ../../fhutiter/src/libfhuti.dll.a binio/libbinio.a ../../mathlibs/src/arpack/libarpack.dll.a /mingw64/lib/libopenblas.dll.a /mingw64/lib/libopenblas.dll.a /mingw64/lib/libopenblas.dll.a -ldl -lm -lstdc++
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldl: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [fem/src/CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/build.make:1484: fem/src/msys-elmersolver.dll] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:16950: fem/src/CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/foo/OneDrive - bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build'
make: *** [Makefile:169: all] Error 2
```

Attempts to resolve this have included explicitly setting the linker in CMake using `set(CMAKE_LINKER "/c/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/ld.exe")`, but this has not resolved the issue.

The branch with the current state of the code is available here:
[ElmerFEM GitHub Branch - wip/windows](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem/tree/wip/windows)

I am looking for insights or suggestions on how to resolve this linking error, particularly how to either correctly include the `libdl` library in this environment or remove the `-ldl` flag from the linking process in a way that's compatible with MSYS/MinGW.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

**P.S.** I have also posted the question [here](https://discord.com/channels/792780131906617355/1184280557249634328) on Discord.

Comment: Not an expert here but is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700097/unable-to-load-shared-library-libdl-so-or-one-of-its-dependencies any help? And can you find a libdl.a or libdl.so anywhere on your system? Also telling us exactly what compiler you are using might help

Comment: @IanBush I was not able to comprehend the relevant [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/700097/167505) you shared. And I don't have any relevant `libdl*` file on my computer. I think I should be looking for `libdl.dll`, right?

Comment: Why is your library name prefixed with `msys-`? I think this is indicative of the [MSYS environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552265/2752075) (note that I'm using this phrase in a different sense than you do, MSYS2 has several environments to choose from, and MSYS is one of them), while `/mingw64` in paths points to the MINGW64 environment. You usually want the latter, and it's weird that the former is getting involved.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am not sure why. You may see [this](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem/blob/wip/windows/buildWindows.bat) cmd/batch script that I use to compile with CMake in the Windows terminal.

Comment: Don't use `/usr/bin/cmake`, use `/mingw64/bin/cmake`. Also I'd prefer compiling from MSYS2 terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Get your libdl for Windows here: https://github.com/dlfcn-win32/dlfcn-win32

There is also an MSYS2 package which you should be able to install, see: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually needed here, or it's just CMake being confused and trying to link it for no reason.