# Possible to force MSYS2 MINGW to build without UCRT?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, mingw, msys2

I'm trying to use MSYS2 MingW to build apps that could still run on Windows 7 (and possibly in XP...).

The executable can't run in Windows 7 because it couldn't find any of those `api-ms-win-*.dll` files and I am also having a hard time trying to bundle up those dll files, for example, `api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-2.dll` is no longer provided by any Windows SDKs anymore (or I can't locate them at all).

One of my major problem is that, MSYS2 (even with the latest update) kept on compiling the executable against, supposedly, obsolete dlls.
I cannot even find them anywhere in any SDKs anymore.

X is "not found" as I reached 30k character limit in this post.
Here is the `ntldd` output:

```
$ ntldd -R src/myprogram.exe 
ADVAPI32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
 ntdll.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
 KERNELBASE.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
  ext-ms-win-advapi32-registry-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-advapi32-registry-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-appcompat-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-ntuser-string-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-file-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-datetime-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-quirks-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-quirks-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-sidebyside-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-mrmcorer-resmanager-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gpapi-grouppolicy-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-ntdsapi-activedirectoryclient-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-ntdsapi-activedirectoryclient-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-shell32-shellcom-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-advapi32-ntmarta-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-security-capauthz-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-feclient-encryptedfile-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-security-efswrt-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-onecore-appmodel-staterepository-cache-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-onecore-appmodel-staterepository-cache-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-onecore-appmodel-staterepository-cache-l1-1-4.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-winrt-storage-win32broker-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-onecore-appmodel-deployment-internal-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appmodel-daxcore-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appmodel-daxcore-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernel32-registry-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernelbase-processthread-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernelbase-processthread-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-kernelbase-processthread-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-advapi32-npusername-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appxdeploymentclient-appxdeploy-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-onecore-appmodel-staterepository-internal-l1-1-4.dll => X
  ext-ms-onecore-appmodel-staterepository-internal-l1-1-6.dll => X
  ext-ms-onecore-appmodel-staterepository-internal-l1-1-3.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appxdeploymentclient-appxdeployonecore-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-cng-rng-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-winrt-device-access-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appmodel-appexecutionalias-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appmodel-appexecutionalias-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appmodel-appexecutionalias-l1-1-3.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-appmodel-appexecutionalias-l1-1-1.dll => X
 SECHOST.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SECHOST.dll
  USERENV.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
   netutils.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll
   logoncli.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\logoncli.dll
    WLDAP32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WLDAP32.dll
    ext-ms-win-smbshare-browserclient-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-profile-userenv-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-profile-userenv-l1-1-1.dll => X
   cldapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cldapi.dll
    FLTLIB.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FLTLIB.DLL
    AEPIC.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AEPIC.dll
     ext-ms-win-appcompat-aeinv-l1-1-0.dll => X
     Bcp47Langs.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Bcp47Langs.dll
      ext-ms-win-ntuser-message-l1-1-1.dll => X
      ext-ms-win-kernel32-localization-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-eventing-rundown-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-security-chambers-l1-1-0.dll => X
 RPCRT4.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
  ext-ms-win-core-winrt-remote-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-rpc-ssl-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-authz-context-l1-1-0.dll => X
  bcryptPrimitives.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
 CRYPTSP.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
 WINTRUST.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINTRUST.dll
  ext-ms-win-advapi32-safer-l1-1-0.dll => X
  imagehlp.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\imagehlp.dll
 CRYPTBASE.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
 SspiCli.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
 bcrypt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
CRYPT32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPT32.dll
 ncrypt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
  NTASN1.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
 profapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
  ext-ms-win-profile-extender-l1-1-0.dll => X
 MSASN1.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
 DPAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.dll
  SAMLIB.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SAMLIB.dll
   DSPARSE.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DSPARSE.dll
 Cabinet.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Cabinet.dll
CRYPTDLG.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTDLG.dll
 CRYPTUI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTUI.dll
  SHLWAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
   SETUPAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SETUPAPI.dll
    SCECLI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SCECLI.dll
     ext-ms-win-setupapi-inf-l1-1-0.dll => X
     ext-ms-win-setupapi-inf-l1-1-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-printer-winspool-l1-1-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-driver-setup-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-shell-shell32-l1-2-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-shell-shlwapi-l1-2-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-uxtheme-themes-l1-1-0.dll => X
    SPFILEQ.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SPFILEQ.dll
    SPINF.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SPINF.dll
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libgdk-3-0.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
 libcairo-gobject-2.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libcairo-gobject-2.dll
 libcairo-2.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libcairo-2.dll
  libfontconfig-1.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll
   libexpat-1.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libexpat-1.dll
  libfreetype-6.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
   libbz2-1.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libbz2-1.dll
   libbrotlidec.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libbrotlidec.dll
    libbrotlicommon.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libbrotlicommon.dll
   libharfbuzz-0.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libharfbuzz-0.dll
    USP10.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USP10.dll
    libgraphite2.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgraphite2.dll
  libpixman-1-0.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpixman-1-0.dll
  libpng16-16.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpng16-16.dll
  zlib1.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\zlib1.dll
 libffi-8.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libffi-8.dll
libgtk-3-0.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
 libatk-1.0-0.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libatk-1.0-0.dll
KERNEL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll
 ext-ms-win-oobe-query-l1-1-0.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-packagevirtualizationcontext-l1-1-0.dll => X
IPHLPAPI.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
 WINNSI.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
 dhcpcsvc.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
  ext-ms-win32-subsystem-query-l1-1-0.dll => X
 dhcpcsvc6.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
 DNSAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
  ext-ms-win-networking-wcmapi-l1-1-0.dll => X
WINHTTP.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
 websocket.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\websocket.dll
 webio.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\webio.dll
  HTTPAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HTTPAPI.dll
  SCHANNEL.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SCHANNEL.dll
   SAMSRV.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SAMSRV.dll
    NETLOGON.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETLOGON.dll
     gmsaclient.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\gmsaclient.dll
     ext-ms-win-branding-winbrand-l1-1-0.dll => X
    cryptdll.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptdll.dll
    ext-ms-win-laps-l1-1-0.dll => X
    setupcl.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\setupcl.dll
   ext-ms-win-ntdsa-activedirectoryserver-l1-1-0.dll => X
   LSASRV.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LSASRV.dll
    LSAADT.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LSAADT.dll
     ext-ms-win-wevtapi-eventlog-l1-1-3.dll => X
     ext-ms-win-wevtapi-eventlog-l1-1-0.dll => X
    Wldp.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
     DEVOBJ.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
      DEVRTL.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVRTL.dll
    FVEAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FVEAPI.dll
     bcd.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcd.dll
     tbs.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\tbs.dll
     FVECERTS.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FVECERTS.dll
     samcli.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\samcli.dll
     ext-ms-win-reinfo-query-l1-1-0.dll => X
     ext-ms-win-devmgmt-policy-l1-1-0.dll => X
     ext-ms-win-feclient-encryptedfile-l1-1-3.dll => X
     dsreg.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dsreg.dll
      certenroll.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\certenroll.dll
       certca.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\certca.dll
       crypttpmeksvc.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\crypttpmeksvc.dll
       CRYPTNET.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTNET.dll
       twinapi.appcore.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\twinapi.appcore.dll
        ext-ms-win-ntuser-rotationmanager-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-appmodel-deployment-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-iam-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-appmodel-usercontext-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-gaming-devicefamily-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-ui-viewmanagement-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-rtcore-minuser-private-ext-l1-1-2.dll => X
        CoreMessaging.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll
         ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-integration-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-rtcore-minuser-private-ext-l1-1-1.dll => X
        CoreUIComponents.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll
         ext-ms-onecore-orientation-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-mininput-inputhost-l1-1-0.dll => X
         SHCORE.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
          ext-ms-win-ntuser-keyboard-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-dpi-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-dpi-l1-2-1.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-dpi-l1-2-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-shell-directory-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-imm-l1-1-0.dll => X
          faultrep.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\faultrep.dll
           ext-ms-win-ntuser-gui-l1-3-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-rtcore-minuser-private-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-rtcore-minuser-internal-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-rtcore-gdi-devcaps-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-dc-access-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-onecore-shellchromeapi-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-appmodel-viewscalefactor-l1-1-0.dll => X
        dcomp.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dcomp.dll
         ext-ms-win-rtcore-minuser-input-l1-1-1.dll => X
         d2d1.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d2d1.dll
          ext-ms-win-direct2d-desktop-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-rtcore-gdi-rgn-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-ntuser-gui-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-ntuser-rectangle-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
          d3d12.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d12.dll
         d3d11.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
          ext-ms-win-dxcore-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dxcore-internal-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dx-d3dkmt-dxcore-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dx-d3dkmt-dxcore-l1-1-3.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dx-d3dkmt-gdi-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-gdi-render-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-onecore-dcomp-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-mf-pal-l2-1-0.dll => X
          d3d11on12.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11on12.dll
          D3DSCache.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\D3DSCache.dll
         dxgi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
          ext-ms-win-dwmapidxgi-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-ntuser-window-l1-1-1.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-ntuser-misc-l1-2-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dx-dxdbhelper-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dx-dxdbhelper-l1-1-2.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dx-dxdbhelper-l1-1-1.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-dwmapidxgi-ext-l1-1-1.dll => X
         wuceffects.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wuceffects.dll
        ContactActivation.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ContactActivation.dll
         UserDataTypeHelperUtil.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UserDataTypeHelperUtil.dll
          dsclient.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dsclient.dll
        ext-ms-win-desktopappx-l1-1-0.dll => X
       DSROLE.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DSROLE.dll
       ext-ms-win-security-credui-l1-1-0.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-security-cryptui-l1-1-0.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-wlan-scard-l1-1-0.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-ntuser-dialogbox-l1-1-0.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-ntuser-private-l1-1-1.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-ntuser-uicontext-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-ntuser-window-l1-1-2.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-ole32-bindctx-l1-1-0.dll => X
       VAULTCLI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VAULTCLI.dll
       NTDSAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTDSAPI.dll
        W32TOPL.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\W32TOPL.dll
       webservices.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\webservices.dll
       WININET.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll
        srpapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\srpapi.dll
         ext-ms-win-security-capauthz-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-ras-rasapi32-l1-1-0.dll => X
        ext-ms-win-security-cryptui-l1-1-1.dll => X
        ESENT.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ESENT.dll
        iertutil.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
         dbgeng.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgeng.dll
          dbgmodel.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgmodel.dll
          WindowsPerformanceRecorderControl.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsPerformanceRecorderControl.dll
        urlmon.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
         wpaxholder.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-ole32-ie-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-appcompat-apphelp-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-gdi-devcaps-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-ntuser-dc-access-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-ntuser-dialogbox-l1-1-1.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-ntuser-draw-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-ntuser-mouse-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-ntuser-window-l1-1-3.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-appmodel-shellexecute-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-win-shell-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll => X
         ext-ms-windowscore-deviceinfo-l1-1-0.dll => X
      webauthn.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\webauthn.dll
       noise.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\noise.dll
       ext-ms-win-session-wtsapi32-l1-1-1.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-security-winscard-l1-1-0.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-security-winscard-l1-1-1.dll => X
       credui.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\credui.dll
        ext-ms-win-security-credui-internal-l1-1-0.dll => X
       HID.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL
      ngcrecovery.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ngcrecovery.dll
      PROPSYS.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
       icu.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\icu.dll
       ext-ms-win-els-elscore-l1-1-0.dll => X
      ext-ms-win-shell-shell32-l1-2-0.dll => X
      ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-cursor-l1-1-0.dll => X
      ext-ms-win-wevtapi-eventlog-l1-1-2.dll => X
     FVESKYBACKUP.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FVESKYBACKUP.dll
     TpmCoreProvisioning.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TpmCoreProvisioning.DLL
      ext-ms-win-session-wtsapi32-l1-1-0.dll => X
      policymanager.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
       msvcp110_win.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcp110_win.dll
       dmenterprisediagnostics.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dmenterprisediagnostics.dll
        ext-ms-win-devmgmt-dm-l1-1-1.dll => X
      ext-ms-win-shell32-shellfolders-l1-1-0.dll => X
     VirtDisk.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VirtDisk.dll
     ext-ms-win-adsi-activeds-l1-1-0.dll => X
    VbsApi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VbsApi.dll
     drvstore.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\drvstore.dll
    AUTHZ.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AUTHZ.dll
     ext-ms-win-authz-remote-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-authz-claimpolicies-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-biometrics-winbio-core-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-firewallapi-webproxy-l1-1-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-netprovision-netprovfw-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-secur32-translatename-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-security-ngc-local-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-security-vaultcli-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-session-winsta-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-samsrv-accountstore-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-security-lsaadt-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-security-lsaadtpriv-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-security-lsaauditrpc-l1-1-0.dll => X
    cryptngc.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptngc.dll
    lsass.exe => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\lsass.exe
     SspiSrv.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiSrv.dll
    FirewallAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FirewallAPI.dll
     fwbase.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\fwbase.dll
      ext-ms-win-shell-embeddedmode-l1-1-0.dll => X
     FWPolicyIOMgr.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FWPolicyIOMgr.dll
    MPR.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
     ext-ms-win-mpr-multipleproviderrouter-l1-1-0.dll => X
    MDMRegistration.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MDMRegistration.DLL
     ext-ms-win-devmgmt-dm-l1-1-2.dll => X
     DMCmnUtils.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DMCmnUtils.dll
      ext-ms-win-wwan-wwapi-l1-1-0.dll => X
      ext-ms-win-wwan-wwapi-l1-1-1.dll => X
     omadmapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\omadmapi.dll
      iri.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iri.dll
      DMPushProxy.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DMPushProxy.dll
      dmEnrollEngine.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dmEnrollEngine.DLL
       unenrollhook.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\unenrollhook.dll
       enterpriseresourcemanager.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\enterpriseresourcemanager.dll
       EDPCSP.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\EDPCSP.dll
        EFSUTIL.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\EFSUTIL.dll
        FeClient.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FeClient.dll
         EFSCORE.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\EFSCORE.dll
          ext-ms-win-edputil-policy-l1-1-1.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-security-efs-l1-1-0.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-feclient-encryptedfile-l1-1-2.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-feclient-encryptedfile-l1-1-1.dll => X
          ext-ms-win-fveapi-query-l1-1-0.dll => X
          edpauditapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edpauditapi.dll
          winmsipc.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\winmsipc.dll
          winipcfile.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\winipcfile.dll
          wevtapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wevtapi.dll
       policymanagerprecheck.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\policymanagerprecheck.dll
        ext-ms-win-biometrics-winbio-core-l1-1-1.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-ci-management-l1-1-0.dll => X
       ext-ms-win-ci-management-l1-1-3.dll => X
      DeclaredConfiguration.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DeclaredConfiguration.dll
     CRYPTXML.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTXML.dll
     ext-ms-win-devmgmt-dm-l1-1-0.dll => X
  TOKENBINDING.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TOKENBINDING.dll
 ext-ms-win-firewallapi-webproxy-l1-1-0.dll => X
 nrtapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\nrtapi.dll
 OLEAUT32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
  msvcp_win.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcp_win.dll
  combase.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
   CFGMGR32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CFGMGR32.dll
   ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-synch-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-ntuser-misc-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-ntuser-private-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-ntuser-windowstation-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-gdi-dc-l1-2-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-gdi-draw-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-gdi-metafile-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-rtcore-gdi-object-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-clbcatq-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-ole32-l1-1-1.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-ole32-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-ole32-l1-1-5.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-ole32-l1-1-3.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-coml2-l1-1-1.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-advapi32-msi-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-kernel32-package-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-kernel32-package-l1-1-2.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-kernel32-package-current-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-appmodel-state-ext-l1-2-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-advapi32-psm-app-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-psmregister-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-session-usermgr-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-apartmentrestriction-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-com-suspendresiliency-l1-1-0.dll => X
   wer.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wer.dll
    DiagnosticDataSettings.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiagnosticDataSettings.dll
    ext-ms-win-ntuser-message-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-ntuser-synch-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-ntuser-window-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-ntuser-windowclass-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-wer-xbox-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-wer-xbox-l1-1-4.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-wer-xbox-l1-1-3.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-wer-ui-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-desktopappx-l1-1-3.dll => X
    dbghelp.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
    NETAPI32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
     wkscli.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wkscli.dll
      ext-ms-win-domainjoin-netjoin-l1-1-0.dll => X
     srvcli.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\srvcli.dll
    UMPDC.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UMPDC.dll
     ext-ms-win-resourcemanager-crm-l1-2-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-session-usertoken-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-wer-xbox-l1-1-2.dll => X
    XmlLite.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
    ext-ms-win-appcompat-aepic-l1-1-0.dll => X
   RMCLIENT.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RMCLIENT.dll
    ext-ms-win-resourcemanager-crm-private-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-sysmain-plmapi-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-hostactivitymanager-ham-private-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-ro-typeresolution-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-ole32-oleautomation-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-sxs-oleautomation-l1-1-0.dll => X
WS2_32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll
 NSI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll
 ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-window-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
msvcrt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
ole32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
 coml2.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\coml2.dll
 ServicingCommon.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ServicingCommon.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll
SHELL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
 ext-ms-onecore-appdefaults-l1-1-0.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-search-folder-l1-1-1.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-com-ole32-l1-1-4.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-com-sta-l1-1-0.dll => X
 WINMM.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
  WINMMBASE.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
   MMDevAPI.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MMDevAPI.DLL
    ext-ms-win-core-resourcepolicy-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-audiocore-pal-l1-2-0.dll => X
  AudioSes.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AudioSes.DLL
   ext-ms-win-audiocore-spatial-l1-1-0.dll => X
   AVRT.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AVRT.dll
   CompPkgSup.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CompPkgSup.DLL
  ext-ms-win-ntuser-server-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-oleacc-l1-1-1.dll => X
 msiltcfg.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msiltcfg.dll
  VERSION.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
 DEVMGR.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVMGR.DLL
  newdev.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\newdev.dll
   WOFUTIL.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WOFUTIL.dll
   ext-ms-win-driver-setup-wu-l1-1-0.dll => X
   ext-ms-win-driver-setup-wu-l1-1-1.dll => X
 dwmapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
 Secur32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
 OLEACC.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll
 DAVHLPR.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DAVHLPR.dll
 CSCAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CSCAPI.dll
 UxTheme.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
 ntshrui.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntshrui.dll
  ACTIVEDS.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ACTIVEDS.dll
   adsldpc.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\adsldpc.dll
    ext-ms-win-security-credui-l1-1-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-advapi32-lsa-l1-1-0.dll => X
  WINSPOOL.DRV => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
   Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll
    ext-ms-win-printer-winspool-core-l1-1-0.dll => X
    PdmUtilities.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-printer-prntvpt-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-printer-prntvpt-l1-1-2.dll => X
 POWRPROF.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\POWRPROF.dll
  WMICLNT.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WMICLNT.dll
 SHDOCVW.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHDOCVW.dll
  TWINAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TWINAPI.dll
   TextInputFramework.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextInputFramework.dll
    ext-ms-win-tsf-msctf-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-tsf-msctf-l1-1-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-ntuser-private-l1-3-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-ntuser-private-l1-2-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-ntuser-keyboard-l1-3-1.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-dwmapi-ext-l1-1-0.dll => X
    ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-private-l1-1-1.dll => X
 EFSADU.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\EFSADU.dll
  MFC42u.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MFC42u.dll
   COMDLG32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\COMDLG32.dll
    dfscli.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dfscli.dll
    PRINTUI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PRINTUI.dll
     puiapi.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\puiapi.dll
     ACLUI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ACLUI.dll
    fms.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\fms.dll
   COMCTL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.22621.2506_none_b43bab19638c9595\COMCTL32.dll
   OLEDLG.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEDLG.dll
   ext-ms-win-odbc-odbc32-l1-1-0.dll => X
 DUser.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DUser.dll
  ext-ms-win-sysmain-pfsapi-l1-1-0.dll => X
 WTSAPI32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
  REGAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\REGAPI.dll
  BROWCLI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\BROWCLI.dll
 DUI70.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DUI70.dll
 apphelp.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
 ADVPACK.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVPACK.dll
 WINBRAND.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINBRAND.dll
  ext-ms-win-core-pkeyhelper-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-resources-languageoverlay-l1-1-1.dll => X
 WindowsCodecs.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
 elscore.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\elscore.dll
 gdiplus.dll => C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.22621.2506_none_57f74dcece1b5ace\gdiplus.dll
  DWrite.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DWrite.dll
   TextShaping.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextShaping.dll
 IMM32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.dll
 CHARTV.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CHARTV.dll
 MrmCoreR.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MrmCoreR.dll
  bcp47mrm.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcp47mrm.dll
  ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-syscolors-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-resources-deployment-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-resources-languageoverlay-l1-1-6.dll => X
 efswrt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\efswrt.dll
  ext-ms-win-winrt-storage-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-rdr-davhlpr-l1-1-0.dll => X
 edputil.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edputil.dll
  ext-ms-win-ntuser-draw-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-ntuser-misc-l1-5-1.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-devmgmt-policy-l1-1-1.dll => X
 LINKINFO.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll
  ext-ms-win-shell-ntshrui-l1-1-0.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-storage-sense-l1-2-0.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-storage-sense-l1-2-3.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-storage-sense-l1-2-2.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-storage-sense-l1-1-0.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-gui-dui70-l1-1-0.dll => X
 HvsiFileTrust.dll => X
 MSCTF.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
  WTDSENSOR.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTDSENSOR.dll
 HwReqChk.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HwReqChk.dll
 ext-ms-win-shell-fileplaceholder-l1-1-0.dll => X
libstdc++-6.dll => C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
USER32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
 win32u.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\win32u.dll
 GDI32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
  ext-ms-win-gdi-dc-l1-2-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-dc-create-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-draw-l1-1-3.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-draw-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-draw-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-font-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-font-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-font-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-font-l1-1-3.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-metafile-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-metafile-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-path-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-print-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-private-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-wcs-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-clipping-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-internal-uap-init-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-internal-desktop-l1-1-0.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-internal-desktop-l1-1-1.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-internal-desktop-l1-1-3.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-internal-desktop-l1-1-2.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-internal-desktop-l1-1-4.dll => X
  ext-ms-win-gdi-edgegdi-l1-1-0.dll => X
 MSIMG32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll
 WINSTA.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSTA.dll
  ext-ms-win-rtcore-ntuser-sysparams-l1-1-0.dll => X
 ext-ms-win-edputil-policy-l1-1-0.dll => X
 wtdccm.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wtdccm.dll
```

[image]

Comment: There's UCRT64 environment and there's MINGW64 environment. ([What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075)) The latter should do what you want? But I'm not sure if the result will run on Win 7.

Comment: You are asking about the UCRT but your problem sounds like you want to avoid using [API sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets).

Comment: @IInspectable Well is not like I want to use the API sets though, it was being historically using it since many years ago (and was fine), is just that with the latest MSYS2, it kept compiling it against obsolete dll such as `api-ms-win-core-console-l3-2-0.dll` which isn't even available anywhere anymore... like, where do you find that dll even?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, I am aware of the UCRT64 environment, that would be my last resort, as I basically have to setup the whole environment from scratch and we have Makefile with flags that was specifically for MingW. So that might involve a lot of changes. If I could just find those missing DLLs, I'd just bundle them up and call it a day. Do you know where I could find the `api-ms-win-core-console-l3-2-0.dll` and `api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-2.dll`?

Comment: Those aren't redistributable files. However, they are just forwarders anyway, so you could instead link against the DLLs that implement and export the functions. You just need to create an appropriate import library.

Comment: I didn't suggest to use UCRT64, I suggested MINGW64 (since you don't want UCRT?).

Comment: Hi @HolyBlackCat or @IInspectable is it possible to statically link the `windowsapp.a` and `kernel32.a` provided by `mingw64` (I saw they were in `/mingw64/lib`)? Or, if I provide the Windows SDK `windowsapp.lib` and `kernel32.lib`, how can I statically link them with MingW or UCRT?

Comment: `.a` are already static. `.dll` or `.dll.a` would be dynamic.

Comment: Please show the output of `ntldd -R my_app.exe` (you can install ntldd from msys2), for both MINGW64 and UCRT64.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Updated, and I've reached the maximum character I could post in a question. I tried changing the code to only use `LoadLibraryA` in order to load the `kernel32.dll` directly without referencing others `api-ms-win-*`... but ultimately, it still asks for `api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll` which is no where to be found in any SDKs.

Comment: You can upload long texts to pastebin if they don't fit into the post.

Comment: I don't see any `api-ms-win-*` in the log, so I wonder who tries to load them. Or is the log truncated?

Comment: `windowsapp.a` is (presumably) MinGW's reincarnation of the Windows App SDK's `windowsapp.lib` [umbrella library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-umbrella-libraries). Umbrella libraries make managing [API Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets) feasible. API Sets are meaningful when targeting the UWP, a platform Microsoft has given up. If you want to target Windows 7-, don't pass umbrella import libraries to the linker.

Comment: you'd have to use an old version of msys2 that still supports win7