# CMake fail to link SDL2_Image statically

Tags: cmake, sdl, sdl-2

System   : `Windows 11 22H2`

ToolChain: `MSYS2 UCRT64`

`CMakeList.txt` below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(sdl_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_mixer REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(sdl_test main.cpp
        sdl_bindings/window.cpp
        sdl_bindings/window.h
        sdl_bindings/renderer.cpp
        sdl_bindings/renderer.h
        sdl_bindings/texture.cpp
        sdl_bindings/texture.h
        sdl_bindings/surface.cpp
        sdl_bindings/surface.h
        sdl_bindings/image.cpp
        sdl_bindings/image.h
        sdl_bindings/font.cpp
        sdl_bindings/font.h)


#include_directories(
#        "C:/clibs/SDL2_mingw/SDL2-2.28.5/include/SDL2"
#        "C:/clibs/SDL2_mingw/SDL2_image-2.6.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2"
#        "C:/clibs/SDL2_mingw/SDL2_ttf-2.20.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2"
#        "C:/clibs/SDL2_mingw/SDL2_mixer-2.6.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2"
#)
# include dir above not correct and misleading, change to:

include_directories(
        ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


target_link_libraries(
        sdl_test
        SDL2::SDL2main
        SDL2::SDL2
        SDL2_image::SDL2_image
        SDL2_ttf::SDL2_ttf
        SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer
)
```

By configurinng this `CMakeList.txt`, i got `"INTERFACE_SDL2_SHARED property not agree"`:

```
C:\packages\MSYS2\ucrt64\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/packages/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/packages/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/packages/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" -S C:\workspace\cpp\sdl_test -B C:\workspace\cpp\sdl_test\cmake-build-debug-msys2
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The INTERFACE_SDL2_SHARED property of "SDL2_image::SDL2_image" does
not agree with the value of SDL2_SHARED already determined
for "sdl_test".

-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

If I try to add suffix `static` for `image`, `ttf` and `mixer` lib, like:

```
target_link_libraries(
        sdl_test
        SDL2::SDL2main
        SDL2::SDL2-static
        SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static
        SDL2_ttf::SDL2_ttf-static
        SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer-static
)
```

I got `"target not found"`:

```
C:\packages\MSYS2\ucrt64\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/packages/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/packages/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/packages/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" -S C:\workspace\cpp\sdl_test -B C:\workspace\cpp\sdl_test\cmake-build-debug-msys2
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:59 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "sdl_test" links to:

    SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.
```

The static lib does exist under  `C:\packages\MSYS2\ucrt64\lib`, but how can I link them by CMake?

[image]

I also wondering how do I know I need to add the word `SDL2::SDL2-static` (but not something like `SDL2::static-SDL2` or `SDL2::SDL2`) in the target link library list. I cannot see the return value or any side effects of `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)`, if I don't go deep to files like `FindSDL2.cmake`.

Comment: Unsure if this is what causes the problem or not: Since you're using MSYS2, you should just install SDL2 from it. CMake will then find it automatically. (The version of SDL2 that you've downloaded is likely incompatible with [UCRT64 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075) anyway, only with MINGW64.) In any case, `CMakeLists.txt` shouldn't contain any hardcoded library paths, they should be specified with command line flags instead (which isn't necessary when installing libs from MSYS2).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I am sorry. My `include dir` above is in-correct and misleading. Now I have fixed that. Actually, I did install the `SDL2`, `SDL2_image`, `SDL2_tff`, `SDL2_mixer` packages inside `MSYS2 UCRT64` terminal by `pacman`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thx. I have checked the CMakeCache.txt. And found that the libs dir CMake find is not those in `ucrt64/lib`, but another dir `xxx/SDL2_MSVC`, this is what I download for Visual Studio. After I delete  `xxx/SDL2_MSVC`, `SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static` and other static libs is then valid.