# What is the correct way to install meson in MSYS2?

Tags: msys2, meson-build

If I simply do `pacman -S meson`, it installs, but then:

```
ERROR: This python3 seems to be msys/python on MSYS2 Windows, but you are in a MinGW environment
ERROR: Please install and use mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 and/or mingw-w64-x86_64-meson with Pacman
ERROR: This python3 seems to be msys/python on MSYS2 Windows, but you are in a MinGW environment
ERROR: Please install and use mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 and/or mingw-w64-x86_64-meson with Pacman
```

I am not in a mingw environment, I am in an MSYS2 window, mingw is not installed on this system.

If I do what it says and `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-meson`, then there is no meson available in my MSYS2 shell:

```
/bin/sh: line 1: meson: command not found
/bin/sh: line 2: meson: command not found
```

How can I correctly install meson so that it will run in MSYS2?

Comment: If meson is not correctly detecting the environment, is there a workaround to disable this check?

Comment: *"I am in an MSYS2 window, mingw is not installed on this system"* MSYS2 has something called "environments", and some of them are mingw environments. You need to read [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075). Meson is likely correct, but prints the wrong package names. Assuming you're in UCRT environment, you need `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-python3 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-meson`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - By "MSYS2 window" I meant "msys environment" - poor choice of phrase, they're all "MSYS2 windows".   But I was wrong since it was in fact ucrt.   I was not understanding ucrt is default now, so installed the wrong package.  However, it also seems that meson's logic for this error is also unaware of the ucrt change!   Trying to sort it out with the project atm...