# CMake find_package SDL2_ttf fails on MSYS2 + MinGW-w64

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, sdl-2, find-package

I am trying to build a SDL2 project on Windows under MinGW. The build goes smooth on Arch Linux but when I try to build on Windows I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSDL2_ttf.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2_ttf",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2_ttf" with any
  of the following names:

    SDL2_ttfConfig.cmake
    sdl2_ttf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SDL2_ttf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SDL2_ttf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "SDL2_ttf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I have installed both `mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2` and `mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_ttf` packages. The CMake configuration seems to be also installed properly (in `/mingw64/lib/cmake/SDL2_ttf/sdl2_ttf-config.cmake`)

I use a simple CMake 3.16 configuration featuring `find_package`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(project VERSION 0.0.1)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
    src/[a-z]*.c
)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)

set(C_FLAGS "-rdynamic")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${C_FLAGS}")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      SDL2::SDL2
                      SDL2_ttf
)
```

Comment: I succesfully installed SDL2_ttf and linked to the test project. Can you show the result of the command on the MinGW Bash: `cat /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/SDL2_ttf.pc`?

Comment: What MSYS2 environment are you running? (The magenta text in the terminal prompt.)

Comment: @WusikiJeronii:
```
$ cat /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/SDL2_ttf.pc
prefix=/mingw64
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: SDL2_ttf
Description: ttf library for Simple DirectMedia Layer with FreeType 2 support
Version: 2.20.2
Requires: sdl2 >= 2.0.10
Libs: -L${libdir} -lSDL2_ttf
Cflags: -I${includedir}/SDL2
Requires.private: harfbuzz freetype2
Libs.private:
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ein MSYS? That's what you mean?

Comment: You're mixing up different environments. Read [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been runing the MSYS2 base environment by executing the `msys2.exe`. That's why cmake was looking for library files inside the `/usr/lib/` directory.

@HolyBlackCat have mentioned [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552264/what-are-msys2-environments-how-do-i-pick-one) which mentions how to run the MSYS2 terminal with a correct environent. In my case this is `mingw64.exe`

Comment: No, this is a very bad idea. Read the question I linked.

Comment: I agree with @HolyBlackCat. This is not a good idea. Instead of a good solution, you just made an LLD copy of the file from one environment to the other, Look, there may be 2 problems: either you have problems with the environment and the necessary files are not found (but they are), or there are no files and there is a problem with the package. Here is the installation package https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_ttf.  The sdl2_ttf-config.cmake file is included in this package. If the files are missing from the file system, then you have problems with the package.

Comment: Well, I have omitted the fact that I did simlinks to all `.cmake` files, so the environment should not be mixed up. Is this different then running MSYS for a specific environment?