# C++17 path configuration problem in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

When I try to use the `round()` function, while passing a `double` as the parameter, VSCode shows me this error:

> more than one instance of overloaded function "round" matches the argument list:
>
> function "std::round(float __x)" (declared at line 1756 of "C:\msys64\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-msys\11.3.0\include\c++\cmath")
>
> function "std::round(long double __x)" (declared at line 1760 of "C:\msys64\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-msys\11.3.0\include\c++\cmath")
>
> argument types are: (double)

I'm using C++17 standard, as the `__cplusplus` macro expands to `201703L`. And according to the information I found, `round(double)` should exists in this version.

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::cout << round(double(0)) << std::endl;
}
```

Judging from the error message, I suspect that maybe something is wrong with my c_cpp_properties:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\msys64\\usr\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-pc-msys\\11.3.0\\include\\**",
                "C:\\msys64\\usr\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-pc-msys\\11.3.0\\include-fixed\\**",
                "C:\\msys64\\usr\\include\\**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: The program [compiles here](https://godbolt.org/z/5rasW8fj8). Looks like some configuration problem.

Comment: Have you tried `std::round` instead of `round`?

Comment: @Eljay Yes, I just tried, and it does not work, with a similar error message. (Replace the "round" with "std::round" in the original error message is what I get.)

Comment: You might also try adding `f` suffix to the value that you use for multiplication, so `1.2` becomes `1.2f` - this way it will use floats.

Comment: @whiskeyo -- that assumes that `float` is appropriate for the calculation being done. That's a design decision, not something you should change just to get rid of confusion about a function call.

Comment: How do you compile your code? What compiler flags? Also I suggest reading [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat By pressing the "Debug C/C++ File" button; Where should I look for it?
Also, I can compile my code just fine by directly typing `g++ -g test.cpp -o debug.exe -Wall` in the integrated terminal. And breakpoints doesn't work for me too, it'll just turn into a gray circle whenever the code is running.

Comment: Can you screenshot where you have this button?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://imgur.com/5YWnGIP

Comment: Ah, so this was not a compiler error, but an intellisense error? Also (elaborating on the link above) it's not the best idea to use `usr/bin/g++`. You should be using `ucrt64/bin/g++` or `mingw64/bin/g++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solve this problem for myself. I changed `includePath` in *c_cpp_properties.json* from

```
"${workspaceFolder}/**",
"C:\\msys64\\usr\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-pc-msys\\11.3.0\\include\\**",
"C:\\msys64\\usr\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-pc-msys\\11.3.0\\include-fixed\\**",
"C:\\msys64\\usr\\include\\**"
```

to

```
"${workspaceFolder}/**",
"C:/msys64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++",
"C:/msys64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-msys",
"C:/msys64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/backward",
"C:/msys64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include",
"C:/msys64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include-fixed",
"C:/msys64/usr/include",
"C:/msys64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../lib/../include/w32api"
```

. I get this list from typing `gcc -v -E -x c++ -` in the terminal.

Edit: I found an answered question regarding the meaning of the command: [What are the GCC default include directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories)